# Diarrhea induced by Iron

Tags: diarrhea

Active 70 Year old female asian experienced chronic diarrhea, which subsided when the iron supplements were removed.  Hemoglobin is normal.

Is it possible for the iron in 2 beef meals in one day to cause diarrhea or is iron-induced diarrhea a long term buildup of iron toxicity?

Comment: Please clarify: Supplements and "2 beef meals": is this your way to name the dosage? If it is: just give the dosage from the label? Also, supplements are not the only source of iron…

Comment: Literally:  lunch was a hamburger and dinner was beef & broccoli.  History includes physician recommended iron supplements, which when removed from diet halted chronic diarrhea